# Add ID to the preview div in Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js

I'm trying to add an id attribute to each file uploaded in Dropzone.js, So I can sort it later on.

This is my code:

```
Dropzone.options.pictureDropzone = {
  paramName: "file",
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  init: function() {
    this.on("success", function(file, response) {
        file.serverId = response.id;
        $(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-preview').attr('id', "document-" + file.serverId);
    });
  }
};
```

The line

```
$(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-preview').attr('id', "document-" + file.serverId);
```

Should add the id, but it does nothing.
Tried it with prop() too.

If I choose a different element, it does  work fine. for example, this works for .dz-details

```
$(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-details').attr('id', "document-" + file.serverId);
```

But I cannot seem to find a way to add it to the dz-preview element.

The HTML structure looks like that:

```
<div class="dz-preview dz-processing dz-image-preview dz-success">
    <div class="dz-details"> ... </div>
    <div class="dz-progress"> ... </div>
    <div class="dz-success-mark"> ... </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
this.on("success", function(file, response) {
    file.serverId = response.id;
    $(".dz-preview:last-child").attr('id', "document-" + file.serverId);
});
```

Comment: This will fail spectacularly if the user drops multiple files.

Comment: The library doesnt seem to support access to the actual underlaying jQuery objects. Adding attributes to the file object can be achieved with another eventlistener: http://pastebin.com/p0DCdTrf

Comment: So how to make it for multiple files? @SzczepanHołyszewski

Answer (score 29):

I know this is old but if anyone is still looking for the answer: -

```
      this.on("success", function(file, response) {
          file.previewElement.id = response.id;
      });
```

Comment: what if i want to put ID on existing images from database?

Comment: @Angger check out this ticket for init function handling existing server files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31627155/5221039 then pass in a 4th argument called `id` to the `this.addCustomFile` function, add `file.previewElement.id = id;` somewhere in the function, then in the `for` loop you add the id from the image that comes from the server via your server code (PHP, etc).

Comment: How about multiple files?

Answer (score 6):

Cast the `previewElement` into jQuery object and perform any action.

```
   this.on("success", function(file, response) {
      $(file.previewElement).attr("id", response.id);
  });
```

Comment: `file.serverID = response.id` I used it this way

Comment: How to take it from removedfile? @Bira

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem but tried it through declaring a variable in javascript ,following is code :

```
$("#fileUpload${dropdown}").dropzone(
                {

                    url : "uploadAdditionalFile?name="+$("#fileUpload${dropdown} div:first-child").prop('id'),
                    addRemoveLinks : true,
                    maxFiles : 1,
                    init : function() {
                        var imageId = $("#fileUpload${dropdown} div:first-child").prop('id');
                        this.on("maxfilesexceeded",
                            function(file) {
                                    alert("Only one file can be uploaded at a time");
                                    this.removeFile(file);
                                        });
                                this.on("addedfile",
                                        function(file) {
                                            switch (file.type) {
                                            case 'application/pdf':
                                                this.emit("thumbnail",file,"/sbms/static/img/pdf.png");
                                                break;
                                            case 'application/msword':
                                                this.emit("thumbnail",file,"/sbms/static/img/word.png");
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                );
                                 this.on('removedfile', function(file){
                                     $.ajax({
                                            type : "GET",
                                            url : "removeAdditionalMediaPreviewForm?id="+imageId,
                                            dataType : "json",
                                            async : false,
                                            success : function(response) {
                                                if (response.status == 'SUCCESS') {
                                                    alert("File removed successfully.")
                                                }else {
                                                    alert("File not removed successfully.")
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                }); 

                    },

                    success : function(file,response) {
                        var imgName = response;
                        file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
                        console.log("Successfully uploaded :"+ imgName);
                    },
                    error : function(file,response, xhr) {
                        alert("Unable to upload file. Please check if it is a valid doc or pdf file.");
                        this.removeFile(file);
                    }
                });
```

imageId is a variable which stores the id and is used later on while file remove.

Answer (score 0):

> This will fail spectacularly if the user drops multiple files.(Szczepan Hołyszewski Dec 17 '15 at 18:45);

BryanFoong answer won't fail if you set the option `uploadMultiple: false`. Which is set so by default. In this case Dropzone sends separate request to the server for each file. Therefore "success" event triggers for each individual file.

In case the `uploadMultiple: true`. Dropzone will send single request to server for all files. And "success" event will trigger once. And following code will handle that.

```js
    YourDropzoneInstance.on("success", function(file, response) {
        response.files.forEach(function(file) {
            file.previewTemplate.id = file.id;
        })
    })
```

Again you need to return from server array of files.
In PHP it will look like

```php
    function yourFileUploadHandler() {
        ...
        // your server file upload implementation        

        $response = [
            "files" => [
                ["id" = 1, ...],
                ["id" = 2, ...],
                ...
             ],
        ];
    
        return json_decode($response);
    }
```