# Populating a dropzone with files from the server - async

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, dropzone

I'm trying to populate my dropzone with files I'm getting from the server. I found [this post](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627154/dropzone-js-v4-display-existing-files-on-server-with-work-limiting-the-number/31627155#31627155) which seems to do what I want, however it seems I can only call this addCustomFile function while in the init function, and not later after I've asychronisily received my data from the server (with the list of files associated with the object I'm viewing).

```
Dropzone.options.imageDrop = {
    url: "upload.php",
    previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
    params: { taskId: urlParams.get('id')},
    init: function() {
        this.addCustomFile = function(file, thumbnail_url , response){
            this.files.push(file);
            this.emit("addedfile", file);
            this.emit("thumbnail", file, thumbnail_url);
            this.emit("processing", file);
            this.emit("success", file, response , false);
            this.emit("complete", file);
        }
        this.addCustomFile ({ //THIS WORKS
            processing: true,
            accepted: true,
            name: "The name",
            size: 12345,
            type: 'image/jpeg',
            status: Dropzone.SUCCESS
        }, "fine.jpg", {
            status: "success"
        })
    }
}

let imageDropZone = $("#imageDrop").dropzone();
imageDropZone.addCustomFile ({ //THIS DOESN'T WORK - addCustomFile is not a function
    processing: true,
    accepted: true,
    name: "The name",
    size: 12345,
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    status: Dropzone.SUCCESS
}, "fine.jpg", {
    status: "success"
})
```

Any thoughts on how to best modify this so I can call it in a async function after the dropzone has been created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this using promises. I had to define a variable for a promise as well as one for the data that would both be in scope across the code. Then create the promise during the init and resolve it inside my other async call. Updated code below:

```
var imageLoadDefer; //Variable that will get a promise
var slowLoaded; //Variable that will get loaded with data async
Dropzone.options.imageDrop = {
url: "upload.php",
previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
params: { taskId: urlParams.get('id')},
init: function() {
    this.addCustomFile = function(file, thumbnail_url , response){
        this.files.push(file);
        this.emit("addedfile", file);
        this.emit("thumbnail", file, thumbnail_url);
        this.emit("processing", file);
        this.emit("success", file, response , false);
        this.emit("complete", file);
     }
     //Create the promise using jQuery
     imageLoadDefer =$.Deferred();
     //Important: Make sure to put this into a variable that can be used in the following function
      var imDrop = this;
      imageLoadDefer.always(function(){
            //promise is resolved and variable is now populated
            imDrop.addCustomFile ({ //THIS WORKS NOW, ASYNC
                processing: true,
                accepted: true,
                name: slowLoaded.name,
                size: slowLoaded.size,
                type: 'image/jpeg',
                status: Dropzone.SUCCESS
            }, slowLoaded.thumbnail, {
                status: "success"
            });
       });
    }
}

let imageDropZone = $("#imageDrop").dropzone();
$.getJSON('images.json', function (data) { 
        slowLoaded = data;
        imageLoadDefer.resolve(); //data loaded so resolve image promise
}
```